# How to use itself in Java interface callback?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

Just like this:

```
AdListener adListener = new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        unRegisterCallback(adListener);
    }
};
```

At this point IDEA will prompt: "Variable 'adListener' might not have been initialized"

How to resolve?

I haven't encountered this kind of problem before, so I can't find a suitable solution.

Comment: You should be able to use "this". Note that "this" won't work in a lambda, though, in which case you will need to use an intermediate object to store a reference to the lambda such as AtomicReference or an array.